Hibernate Search Lucene with file system
I'm new to Hibernate-Search 7.1.1.Final and trying to achieve some basic functionality to work taking reference of this. I'm able to index the data. But can't make the search work. Each time I make change to fix something I get different exception. I can't find proper beginner guides/examples anywhere on the internet for common use cases. Please help me to properly apply search functionality without database integration. (I will fetch data from other means and then have some list of MetadataSearch objects and I want to pass this data to hibernate search to do bulk index).
Few of the exceptions I receive are
org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000614: Cannot project on entity type 'MetadataSearch': this type cannot be loaded from an external datasource, and the documents from the index cannot be projected to its Java class 'MetadataSearch'. To enable loading of entity instances from an external source, provide a SelectionLoadingStrategy when registering the entity type to the mapping builder. To enable projections turning taking index data into entity instances, annotate a constructor of the entity type with @ProjectionConstructor.See the reference documentation for more information.
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HSEARCH900004: 'projections' must not be null or empty."

I'm using the following dependencies in my Spring Boot Project.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-standalone</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
        </dependency>

This is my model class
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

import org.hibernate.search.engine.backend.types.Projectable;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.definition.annotation.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Indexed
public class MetadataSearch {

    @DocumentId private Integer id;

    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private Integer oId;

    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private Integer cId;

    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private Integer oParentId;

    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private Integer oType;

    private Integer oStartVersion;

    private Integer oEndVersion;

    @FullTextField(projectable = Projectable.YES, analyzer = "english")
    private String oName;

    @FullTextField(analyzer = "english", projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private String oPhysicalName;

    @FullTextField(analyzer = "english", projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private String oDefinition;

    @FullTextField(analyzer = "english", projectable = Projectable.YES)
    private String oComment;

}

This my Configuration file
import org.hibernate.search.engine.environment.bean.BeanReference;
import org.hibernate.search.engine.environment.bean.BeanRetrieval;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.definition.annotation.AnnotatedTypeSource;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.mapping.CloseableSearchMapping;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.mapping.SearchMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class SearchConfig {

    @Value("${lucene.index-dir}")
    private String indexDir;

    @Bean
    public CloseableSearchMapping searchMapping() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.search.backend.directory.root", indexDir);
        properties.put(
                "hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer",
                BeanReference.of(LuceneAnalysisConfig.class, BeanRetrieval.CLASS));
        properties.put(
                "hibernate.search.mapping.configurer",
                BeanReference.of(SearchMappingConfig.class, BeanRetrieval.CLASS));
        return SearchMapping.builder(AnnotatedTypeSource.fromClasses(MetadataSearch.class))
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }
}

This is my Mapping Config and Lucene Analysis Config file
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.definition.programmatic.ProgrammaticMappingConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.definition.programmatic.TypeMappingStep;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.mapping.StandalonePojoMappingConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.mapping.StandalonePojoMappingConfigurer;

public class SearchMappingConfig implements StandalonePojoMappingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(StandalonePojoMappingConfigurationContext context) {
        context.annotationMapping()
                .discoverAnnotationsFromReferencedTypes(false)
                .discoverAnnotatedTypesFromRootMappingAnnotations(false);
        ProgrammaticMappingConfigurationContext mappingContext = context.programmaticMapping();
        TypeMappingStep mappingStep = mappingContext.type(MetadataSearch.class);
        mappingStep.searchEntity();
        mappingStep.indexed();
        mappingStep.property("id").documentId();
        mappingStep.property("oName");
    }
}


import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurer;

public class LuceneAnalysisConfig implements LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
        context.analyzer("english")
                .custom()
                .tokenizer("standard")
                .tokenFilter("lowercase")
                .tokenFilter("snowballPorter")
                .param("language", "English")
                .tokenFilter("asciiFolding");

        context.analyzer("name")
                .custom()
                .tokenizer("standard")
                .tokenFilter("lowercase")
                .tokenFilter("asciiFolding");
    }
}

This is the service class
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import org.hibernate.search.engine.search.query.SearchResult;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.mapping.CloseableSearchMapping;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.standalone.session.SearchSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SearchService {

    private final CloseableSearchMapping searchMapping;

    public boolean index() {
        try (SearchSession session = searchMapping.createSession()) {
            MetadataSearch metadata =
                    new MetadataSearch()
                            .setId(6553610)
                            .setCId(65536)
                            .setOId(1)
                            .setOParentId(0)
                            .setOName("Hello")
                            .setOPhysicalName("hello")
                            .setODefinition("hello def)
                            .setOComment("hello comment");
            session.indexingPlan().addOrUpdate(metadata);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Optional<MetadataDetails> search() {
        try (SearchSession session = searchMapping.createSession()) {
            SearchResult<MetadataSearch> metadataResults =
                    session.search(MetadataSearch.class)
                            .where(f -> f.wildcard().fields("oName").matching("hello"))
                            .fetch(5);
            long totalHitCount = metadataResults.total().hitCount();
            List<MetadataSearch> metadataList = metadataResults.hits();
            MetadataDetails metadataDetails =
                    MetadataDetails.builder()
                            .metadata(metadataList)
                            .totalHitCount(totalHitCount)
                            .build();
            return Optional.of(metadataDetails);
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to call the two services from a controller, the index method works fine. When I wanted to test the search method, it throws exception.

The getting started guide you've referred to in your question uses the projection API
.select( f -> f.id( Integer.class ) )

you have two options here, you can either use this projection API, in particular you can try a projection constructor.
Or you can define a loading binder for your search entity.
In your particular case it seems that the projection API would be a way to go. So define a projection constructor either in your MetadataDetails or create some MetadataDetailsProjection with the data you want to get back and then:
session.search(MetadataSearch.class)
        .select(MetadataDetailsProjection.class)
        .where(f -> f.wildcard().fields("oName").matching("hello"))
        .fetch(5);

